# changing pseudo tty echo mode from the master side

Tags: c, linux, pty

On linux, I am opening a pseudo tty on the master side. While there is no client on the slave side, the pseudo tty seems to be echoing everything I am writing to him, which is not what I am expecting.
Consider the folowing code :

```
int  main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int ptyfd;
    int rc;     /* return code */
    char readbuf[3];
    ptyfd = open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    die_on_error(ptyfd, "open ptmx");

    /* unlock and print slave name */
    rc = unlockpt(ptyfd);
    die_on_error(rc, "unlockpt");
    printf("Slave pts name : %s\n", ptsname(ptyfd));

    write(ptyfd, "C", 1);
    rc=read(ptyfd, readbuf, 1);
    die_on_error(rc, "read");
    printf("read returned %c\n",readbuf[0]);
    return 0;   
}
```

When I run this program, I would expect the read call to block, but instead it immediately returns and the readbuf content is C. How can I change this behaviour ? When the slave side is not opened, I would like the character written on the master side to either vanish or be fifoed for later reading by the slave side.

Is changing the master side attributes the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the master side was not a tty, but apparently it is, so you can call things like `tcgettattr` and `tcsetattr`, and suppress the echo.

Comment: Yes this works under Linux and BSDs, as they put the TTY/termios semantics on the master side as well. But thats not reliable for 2 reasons: not POSIX conform (cannot be expected to work), termios handling is meant for the program in charge on slave side, it might revert custom termios settings from elsewhere at any point (and complicated interactive programs will do that for sure or those settings might confuse the programs tty interactions).

Answer (score 1):

None of the older answers provided the correct C code, so here it is:

```
struct termios tmios;
tcgetattr(ptfd, &tmios);
tmios.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO);
tcsetattr(ptfd, TCSANOW, &tmios);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the blocking `getch()` call. Also `getch()` will not echo the content.

Comment: Any references ? I can't see how getch could suppress the echo ?
I know getc, and getchar, but not getch.