# Disable ECHO at PTY Pseudo Termial on Unix in C / C++

Tags: c++, c, unix, tty, pty

I know this question has been asked before, but I simply didn’t achieve to disable echoing in PTY.

I’ve successfully implemented a PTY (Pseudo Terminal): Master which writes STDIN to Slave which executes STDIN and returns the Output which the master tty reads.

But my command gets repeated if I spawn a new process before the output.

I’ve seen [changing pseudo tty echo mode from the master side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482818/changing-pseudo-tty-echo-mode-from-the-master-side):
Do I have to disable the ECHO at the master side or slave because neither worked for mine.

Code example:

```
struct termios tmios;
tcgetattr(ptfd, &tmios); 
tmios.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO);
tcsetattr(ptfd, TCSANOW, &tmios);
```

Thx

Comment: The description is very confusing! What's wrong with `stty -echo`?

Comment: Have you tryed to disable echo in the spawned process?

Comment: @Manuel I tried so using the now above posted code, but it failed

Comment: May be you have to detach the new process from the [controlling](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Functions-for-Job-Control.html#Functions-for-Job-Control) terminal.

Comment: @Manuel That‘s an interesting and helpful way budi. I‘ve already posted the question once {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935707/disable-echoing-pty-pseudo-terminal-in-c-c-unix-set-pty-to-non-echoing} if you‘d like to have a look at the code ;) I appreciate your Help budy

Comment: @U.Windl I apologize for this misunderstanding budy, I‘ve tried stty -echo, but it still repeats my input when I spawn a new process. Have a look at the code {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935707/disable-echoing-pty-pseudo-terminal-in-c-c-unix-set-pty-to-non-echoing}

Comment: @Biggboiiii Two additional notes: 1) You have to disable echo in the *input*, not on the *output*, and 2) if the program explicitly does output, the `stty -echo` won't help; it only helps when using the standard input driver. Actually a complete program and use example would be helpful to understand what's going wrong.